# Why is fitch so popular?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was wondering why almost every other first-order-logic question refer to fitch style deduction?  What is so different about fitch-style deduction that it has to be specified?

Regards.

Comment: Standard undergraduate introduction into logic textbook I suppose...

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Suppose too, I guess.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking But why specify "fitch-proof"? Does he prove it differently than other natural deduction systems?

Comment: I think you are right in questioning this particular tag. It should by a synonym of Fitch or omitted completely.

Comment: I agree that the answer is definitely that it's ubiquitous in intro textbooks and intro classes, so we get a lot of questions that use it. But I don't think this makes sense as a question for meta, right? Like "why is fitch so popular" isn't a meta question about the site that can be discussed to better improve the site in any way. However the question of what to do with the fitch tag, rolling it into natural deduction or whatever else, I think is a good question.

Comment: @Not_Here You are correct, i thought it was a catchy title hence I put it. I mean is there any point in specifying "fitch-proof". I am speaking of experience, for a while I avoided answering question with fitch tag out of fear that I might confuse a questioner in case my natural deduction is different than fitch's. However, after looking at a bunch of questions and answers I realized it is just like any other natural deduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a software product from OpenProof Courseware called "Fitch" that goes with the *Language, Proof and Logic* textbook that appears to be what some people are referring to: https://ggweb.gradegrinder.net/support/manual/fitch  Some of these questioners may be seeking help with this particular software product.

There is also a Fitch-style proof checker that I like to use that goes with the *forall x* textbook: http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

However, the Fitch notation is an indented way to display subproofs in a natural deduction proof that was used by Frederic Brenton Fitch in his *Symbolic Logic*, 1952. Here is an illustration of the notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation

Comment: I see, thanks for the in depth answer!